# Downed Power Line Scenarios

Tags: voltage

In the case where you hit a power line with your car, is it possible if you

a) touch the frame of the car [(i) either one or (ii) both hands] and your body has no contact with the ground, you will not be electrocuted.

Similarly, if you b) open the car door and have one foot on the ground and the other foot still remaining in the car. (keeping in mind that that the body is not in contact with the frame of the car)

I may have misunderstood something, but is the reason that you do not get electrocuted due to the negligible potential difference for scenario a) with both hands and that one hand touching the frame will result in the same reasoning for scenario b) where you are not completing the circuit that you won't get electrocuted?

Thank You!

Comment: You could use a van der graaf generator and stand on a 12" thick block of glass and put a million volts on you relative to ground and you will be OK. Yes, the amount of charge will tend to repel your hair strands (make you hair stand on end so to speak) but you will be OK. Be careful as you step down without slowly discharging your self to prevent a current surge that might be felt as a tingle or tickle.

Comment: Are we meant to assume that the car is in contact with the power line after the accident? Do some research: it has happened to tractor drivers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the case where you hit a power line with your car, is it possible if you
>   a) touch the frame of the car [(i) either one or (ii) both hands] and your body has no contact with the ground, you will not be electrocuted.

It is current through the body that kills. The levels are quite low and we typically set RCD/GFCI devices to 30 mA as a safe limit.

To get current to flow through the body a voltage (potential) difference is required between two points of the body. Since the car's chassis is steel or aluminium all points on the car's chassis will be at the same potential so there is little risk.

> Similarly, if you b) open the car door and have one foot on the ground and the other foot still remaining in the car. (keeping in mind that that the body is not in contact with the frame of the car)

You are relying on the insulation of the carpet and your shoes. This might be OK for domestic voltages but not for distribution voltages.

> I may have misunderstood something, but is the reason that you do not get electrocuted due to the negligible potential difference for scenario a) with both hands and that one hand touching the frame will result in the same reasoning for scenario b) where you are not completing the circuit that you won't get electrocuted?

You are missing the capacitative current.

[image]

*Figure 1. Electric shock through body to ground capacitance. Source: [All About Circuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-3/shock-current-path/).*

I can't find a good illustration but if you imagine that's a capacitor between the guys body and the ground then with AC voltage an AC current will flow through the body capacitance to ground. This effect is used safely in neon screw-driver type phase-testers by including a high value resistor in the circuit. Without that there is danger of electrocution.

For power distribution systems at higher voltages it is common to fit ground fault detection relays which, if a ground fault is detected, connect that phase to ground to reduce the risk to anyone coming in contact with the wire.

Comment: To clarify, if you wanted to put 2 hands on the frame of the car, you would do it both at the same time as putting 1 hand only or putting both hands after a few seconds apart (if you would be alive by then i'm assuming) because of the human body acting as a capacitance. And an example of this would be if I were to dangle on one hand,  touching a high voltage transmission line and the other hand is free whilst suspended in mid air. Is that correct? Thank you so much!

Comment: These are all hypothetical situations. Don't rely on them. Regarding one or two hands at once: it's unlikely to make any difference. If there's a capacitance path to ground it won't make a difference how many parts are touching the car. The high voltage is different as there is a voltage gradient through the air and this can be enough to cause currents to flow through the body. Live-line linesmen wear conductive clothing to eliminate voltage gradient along the body. Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG0KB4XODXk.